# Dockerfile RUN doesn't to run in container context

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, grpc

I'm having an issue trying to generate a dockerfile for my nodejs app:

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "/app/index.js"]
```

The nodejs (As part of npm install) needs grpc. When I try to run my app, I get the following error message:

> Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'

When I explore the `app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/` folder, `node-v48-win32-x64` is the only folder inside there. My guess is when `npm install` ran, it used the context my host machine where it detected windows/x64 and downloaded that binary instead. I'd like to avoid running `npm install` at runtime. How do I fix this?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "microservice-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test microservice.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "FrankerZ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grpcc": "0.0.8",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "grpc": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "protoc-plugin": "0.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Attached

Comment: I would go with dockerfile from this guide https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/
It probably copies your already installed node_modules with your system dependant ones, and does not update to docker ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think is happening is, docker run is copying the local `node_modules` from your project inside the container at `COPY . /app`
 .

So thus you get the linux-x64 error. It basically copied all the machine specific code from node_modules to the container that must have another OS. To fix this, ignore node_modules by making a `.dockerignore` file alongside your `package.json` and add just one line.

`node_modules`

Read more about it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).